# Export interpolated data from ListDensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting, export

Following code is for a 4D graph generated with ListDensityPlot3D using discrete data.

```
data={{1.53425*10^6, 408263., 10176.4, 0.000478544}, {1.22379*10^6, 1.08219*10^6, 12199.4, 0.000337414}, {1.22354*10^6, 1.08089*10^6, 22996.7, 0.0000908914}, {153897., 284973., 17328.8, 0.000273729}, {747132., 997943., 10169.5, 0.000493537}, {1.46188*10^6, 1.02963*10^6, 18449.2, 0.000229882}, {1.1597*10^6, 293823., 10279.8,0.000490992}, {1.45002*10^6, 359502., 19394.1, 0.000207897}, {1.15944*10^6, 397155., 11569.3, 0.000452945}, {858184., 387842., 10842.3, 0.000471545}, {382863., 546302., 19602.7, 0.000197679}, {1.28394*10^6, 436905., 21551., 0.000135311}, {838859., 403809., 11441.3, 0.000457242}, {1.06467*10^6, 1.01268*10^6, 11416.1, 0.00044077}, {682002., 104312., 15745.1, 0.000309205}, {232234., 1.03012*10^6, 13191.5, 0.00039873}, {859095., 91664.2, 22527.1, 0.000112021}, {1.41784*10^6, 547793., 11677.9, 0.00044604}, {1.24618*10^6, 608335., 17002.2, 0.000281444}, {1.13097*10^6, 689136., 19126.3, 0.0002149}, {1.56229*10^6, 332739., 17740.5, 0.000257263}, {555560.,816933., 22599.3, 0.000107527}, {1.39249*10^6, 166093., 18802., 0.000228282}, {1.10934*10^6, 246174., 20789.8, 0.000158522}, {1.31517*10^6, 257510., 13391.9, 0.000383127}, {1.09199*10^6, 829892., 21304.9, 0.000140884}, {441869., 505809., 17274.5, 0.00026961}, {808903., 1.00479*10^6, 13664.9, 0.000371464}, {1.53521*10^6, 413435., 11689.6, 0.000432767}, {1.39324*10^6, 162936., 18364.1, 0.00023803}, {1.16035*10^6, 436560., 11013.6, 0.000467817}, {177850., 305098., 15362.9, 0.000323357}, {1.47475*10^6, 414243., 19750.3, 0.000188751}, {1.21282*10^6, 1.07763*10^6, 10299.6, 0.000487735}, {1.34151*10^6, 42767.6, 22776.5, 0.0000972066}, {1.45716*10^6, 1.02965*10^6, 19754.1, 0.000196494}, {983314., 1.03048*10^6, 20004.3, 0.000189316}, {144776., 614403., 21499.7, 0.000140422}, {1.44524*10^6, 361884., 10413.4, 0.000473819}, {508305., 257400., 20787.2, 0.000164365}, {109299., 831151., 22333.1, 0.000113397}, {1.0323*10^6, 105014., 17755., 0.000256153}, {1.66307*10^6, 311543., 19225., 0.000207677}, {1.53548*10^6, 1.00745*10^6, 22275.2, 0.000120002}, {694698., 833534., 21891., 0.000105638}, {488843., 839296., 21978.7, 0.000122838}, {1.06277*10^6, 1.01985*10^6, 18463.5, 0.000236135}, {678423., 94498.4, 21406.5, 0.000142227}, {101403., 1.02846*10^6, 12309.1, 0.000412496}}

{minx, maxx} = MinMax@data1[[All, 1]]
{miny, maxy} = MinMax@data1[[All, 2]]
{minz, maxz} = MinMax@data1[[All, 3]]
{minf, maxf} = MinMax@data1[[All, 4]]

ListDensityPlot3D[data, OpacityFunction -> 0.05, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}), 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {minf, maxf}}, LegendLabel -> Style[f, 14], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 250]]
```

[image: Velocity distribution]

Now I am trying to export the continuous velocity data of each pixel. How can I export continuous 4D data generated by this graph as a csv file with nice four columns?

I tried the same with contour plots which was working. But I failed with density plots.

Comment: Please provide runable code: `data` missing!

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the code with a data set. Please try now.

Comment: Well, the result is not really continuous: t's interpolated. You could use `Interpolate` on your data directly if you want to generate values where you don't have data.